# I'm using MS Access 2016 SQL to create a nested JOIN clause but I seem to get an error

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

```
SELECT 
    (invoice.invoice_id) AS invoice_id, 
    COUNT (line_item.code) AS code, 
    SUM (price)
FROM
    invoice 
INNER JOIN 
    (line_item 
INNER JOIN 
    (stock_item) ON line_item.code = stock_item.code) ON invoice.invoice_id = line_item.invoice_id;
```

Comment: You either get an error or you don't. And if you do, why not share it? Why make us guess? And code only questions are as much frowned upon as code only answers. You should always explain what you are doing, what you tried and why it didn't work (ie what the error is you get). You are asking people to help you in their own time, just dumping some code and "I seem to get an error" isn't likely to convince people to help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
SELECT i.invoice_id AS invoice_id, COUNT(li.code) AS code, SUM(price)
FROM (line_item as li INNER JOIN 
      stock_item as si
      ON li.code = si.code
     ) INNER JOOIN
     invoice as i
     ON i.invoice_id = li.invoice_id
GROUP BY invoice_id;
```

Note:  I added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: You wrote too fast, quite a few typing errors. And doesn't access need a `group by`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, sorry for that' the error message i am getting is "Your query does not include the specified expression 'invoice_id' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: @Vicsituma you should edit your question to include that information. Although I'm sure if you enter that error message into Google (or any other engine) you'll get more than enough results to identify the problem.

Comment: @Gordon am stil getting the same error message. am trying to get the total value of invoices from 3 joined tables( invoices, line_item and stock_item tables)

Comment: @Vicsituma . . . I added the `GROUP BY`.  I missed that you had an aggregation query without that.